# MongoDB spatial query for Polygons

Tags: mongodb, geospatial, polygon, postgis, srid

I will build a GIS system based on polygons, not just points. I wanted to use MongoDB or PostGIS.

How do this in MongoDB?

[image]

Query A - get the center of a polygon

Query B - distance between two polygons

Query C - list of polygons that are part of a third that I specify

Query D - near-distance of the polygon

Support SRID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB's [geospatial indexing](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) currently only indexes points. Although it does support proximity and bounds queries, documents are matched by a single point. You may be able to take advantage of [multi-location documents](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing/#GeospatialIndexing-MultilocationDocuments) and index multiple points along a polygon, which might support some of your queries with reduced precision; however, that would certainly not be ideal.

PostGIS seems more appropriate for your requirements.